# Can't push viewController because navigationController is nil

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, segue, pushviewcontroller

I can't perform a transition between `viewControllers` because `navigationController` is `nil`. I have logged `navigationController` in different parts of the `class` but it returns nil everywhere. In `storyboard` the `viewController` is embedded in a `navigationController`. I have checked other threads on `SO` with the same issue, but none of the answer has helped or even really made sense to me.

[Can't push because self.navigationController is nil](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29656974/cant-push-because-self-navigationcontroller-is-nil)

[navigationController is nil,when push the viewcontroller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50001505/navigationcontroller-is-nil-when-push-the-viewcontroller)

Why is it nil? And how do I solve this? An error message is also returned:

I have tried both using a `segue`:

```
 [self.navigationController performSegueWithIdentifier:@"experienceDetails" sender:self];
```

as well as pushing:

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Inspiration" bundle:nil];
ExperienceViewController *viewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"experience"];            
[self.navigationController pushViewController:viewController animated:NO];
```

Nothing happens using `push` but an error message is produced:

> Attempting to load the view of a view controller while it is deallocating is not allowed and may result in undefined behavior

I have looked for solutions on that error too, but there doesn't seem to be a clear and concrete answer to how to solve it. Again, those suggestions I read and tried didn't work.

I'm really at a loss here. Such a simple thing to do but I'm hindered by something I don't even understand.

***EDIT***
If it helps, I have a `tab bar` and in one `item` I have the `viewController` that is embedded in a `navigationController` and from there I want to `push` to another `viewController` within the same `storyboard`.

***EDIT***
I got this to work:

```
 [self showViewController:viewController sender:self];
```

very likely because it doesn't use `navigationController`. Its presented as `modular` though and is not part of the navigation stack, which is not something I want. Just good to know that things would work if `navigationController` wasn't nil.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reproduced the described behaviour when segue *experienceDetails* was created from navigation controller... and here is solution

1) deleted segue *experienceDetails* form navigation controller

2) created `push` segue with identifier *experienceDetails* from included view controller to detail view controller

3) in view controller performed segue from `self` as below

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"experienceDetails" sender:self];
```

Comment: Nice, it worked, thanks. Still need to figure out why navController is nil as I want this vc to be in the stack.